# Changing lower_case_table_names variable in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a test Linux server running the database for test, but locally I'm working on a windows. This means that my `lower_case_table_names` variable is set to `1`, so basically my table names case sensitive, whereas it's set to `0` by default on Linux.

I tried altering the variable in the `my.ini` located in my installation directory (`C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.0\data\my.ini`). Before these changes apply, I do need to restart the service.

I went into my services and stopped the `MySql` service. Trying to start it again however, I get error:

> 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly

So I suppose MariaDB cannot understand the `my.ini` configuration.

As I understood it by reading the documentation, this is one of the ways to actually do this. Removing the `lower_case_table_names` variable from the `my.ini` file, the service can start again.

How can I set the variable so my tables names are case-sensitive?

**EDIT**

Setting that variable to either `1`or `2` the service can start fine again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names):

> As of MySQL 5.5.46, an error message is printed and the server exits
>   if you attempt to start the server with --lower_case_table_names=0 on
>   a case-insensitive file system.

Same applies to MariaDB.

Comment: So no way to get normal table names with uppercase in them on Windows?

Comment: Setting the lower_case_table_names=2 solved my problems on windows. It would keep the uppercase letters like I wanted. So I suggest setting it to 2.

Answer (score 3):

Like elenst stated an error message might appear if setting lower_case_table_names to OFF or 0 on a system that has lower_case_file_system ON or 1. The asker develops on a Windows system but, as so many, deploys on a linux system that does offer case sensitivity and might run in to compatibility issues where something might work in developement but not in deployment.

Contrary to popular believe Windows (> NT) allows for case sensitive file systems and NTFS supports case sensitive files from its inception and case sensitive even can (must) be set on a per folder basis. Neat. If the location and content of the data files on mariadb (e.g. mariadb\data) is set to case sensitive behavior the lower_case_table_name value can be set to 0 in my.ini under [mysqld].

```
lower_case_table_names = 0
```

Here is my result of

```
select @@lower_case_file_system, @@lower_case_table_names;
```

on a Windows 10 system (running wampserver, with mariadb 10.4.10:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| @@lower_case_file_system | @@lower_case_table_names |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|                        0 |                        0 |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Perfect.

So the quenstion remains how to set the data folder to case sensitive? The fsutil can set the flag for case senstive to folders after the files where created. The command is as follows:

```
fsutil file setcasesensitiveinfo *data* enable
```

where data takes a folder name. There is one culprit, the command does not support recursively setting all subfolders at once. A simple PS script does this wonder:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\wamp64\bin\mariadb\mariadb10.4.10\data -Directory -Recurse | foreach {fsutil file SetCaseSensitiveInfo $_.Fullname}
```

Obviously you will have to change the path to *your* data folder, not mine.

Remark: One of the many bugs in MySQL Workbench is that it does not understand this quite and assumes, wrongly, a lower_case_file_system=1 when on Windows and therefor complains about Server configuration Problems.

And a word of caution. Although the OS and the FS suport case senstivity splenditly many application do not understand so. But you shouldn't be messing with your MySQL or MariaDB data folder with other application, in the first place.

Let me know if you do run in problems.

Comment: Thanks - this has helped me a lot.
Side note: the recursive script alone does not change the attributes on the data folder itself, which was also necessary to get it working.